# How do i use GSON for such response

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a server response which is in this format, please help me by suggesting how can GSON be used :

```
[
  [
    12345678910,
    "ABCDEFG",
    "PRASHJDXSAD",
    "ASDASDWW"
  ],
  [
    08909809887,
    "HIJKLPM",
    "SDASDSD",
    "PRASHJDXSAD"
  ],
  [
    8798798787987,
    "DASDAS",
    "ASDASDSD",
    "QWEWQEW"
  ],
  [
    679879879897,
    "DDSDSDSDS",
    "AASWEWQE",
    "ASDASDDD"
  ]
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a simple two-dimensional array. What is your question? Post your code and show what issues you're having.

Comment: @AleksG: I m new to GSON, every time i used it. I provide a JAVA object with defined structure. But this is 2D array is new to me

Comment: I think it should be something like List<List<String>>, but I don't get what's the problem with that?

Comment: @Chaosit: But there is long in the first element

Comment: Oh I see now, then I can't think of anything better than defining this field as <List<List<Object>>, this should work

Comment: Then how will i get those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [TypeToken](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), and used `List<Object[]>` to have an access for each element. Here's how.

```
    String json = "[[12345678910,\"ABCDEFG\",\"PRASHJDXSAD\",\"ASDASDWW\"],[08909809887,\"HIJKLPM\",\"SDASDSD\",\"PRASHJDXSAD\"],[8798798787987,\"DASDAS\",\"ASDASDSD\",\"QWEWQEW\"],[679879879897,\"DDSDSDSDS\",\"AASWEWQE\",\"ASDASDDD\"]]";
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Object[]>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Object[]> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    Object[] t = (Object[]) list.get(0); //[12345678910,"ABCDEFG","PRASHJDXSAD","ASDASDWW"]
    long x = Math.round((Double)t[0]); //t[0] is Double.
    System.out.println(x); //12345678910
```